# How can you provide WhatsApp a picture to show next to an URL?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, whatsapp

I have a website https://indiauthority.marketing but when sharing post via Android Smartphone to WhatsApp no Thumbnail or Featured image shown in WhatsApp. When site first time launch 1-2 post shown with Post image but due to Plugin or something els now no post show Featured Post or Thumbnail when sharing to WhatsApp. Please help to solve this issue. Platform of Website is WordPress, theme with latest Updated and all plugin are also updated. show the process or provide guideline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing Thumbnail for link in WhatsApp || og:image meta-tag doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100917/showing-thumbnail-for-link-in-whatsapp-ogimage-meta-tag-doesnt-work)

Comment: I am also searching, but no answer found.