# Rich preview of Video in Android SMS

Tags: android, facebook-opengraph

Does Android sms support Open graph Video tag? We cannot see play video when sent as a simple SMS on Android

We tried using OG:Video

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400065/open-graph-sms-rich-messages-on-android-and-ios

Comment: Kindly add some code, so that one can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Below is the code snippet we used Inside html    <meta property ="og:video:secure_url" content ="https://randomyoutubeurl" />

Comment: Og:width is 176 and height is 144, we are Trying to send the video url in sms but andriod sms is not showing preview

Comment: @napoli thanks but that is not working when sent in sms for Andriod