# How to share this link on whatsapp with it's thumbnail image?

Tags: angular, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp

http://52.187.72.102/ProjectByteServices/Module/1.html.

This link appears broken. I've sanitized it using angular 2. It shows thumbnail on both facebook and twitter bu[image]t not on whatsapp.

Comment: please give more Information. Are you running a Angular-Universal server ? how did you implement opengraph ? Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100917/showing-thumbnail-for-link-in-whatsapp-ogimage-meta-tag-doesnt-work

Comment: I've posted a screenshot above @Joniras. The portion in red is becoming url. However I want the full url

Comment: You did not answer my question... Are you implementing the server behind 52.187.72.102 ?