# How to get URL pre loaded in Text view

Tags: android, textview

If we paste a `url` in Whatsapp or Facebook those url's would loaded with headers text.

How can I load such text type of in my `textview`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing Thumbnail for link in WhatsApp || og:image meta-tag doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100917/showing-thumbnail-for-link-in-whatsapp-ogimage-meta-tag-doesnt-work)

Comment: this lib will help you https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview

Answer (score 0):

Well you need 2 things for achieve that

1: URL with meta data [like this link says](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)

2: Read meta data from the provided link [library for extracting metadata](https://github.com/onehilltech/android-metadata)

I hope it helps.