# WhatsApp does not show image thumbnail for website

Tags: html, django, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, whatsapp

I followed all steps mentioned in these top-voted answers:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43154489/8407719
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32154775/8407719

This is a sample code in my `base.html` template in my Django Application deployed on Heroku:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Website Name">
<meta property="og:title" content="Website Name"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/"/>
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" itemprop="image" content="https://i.ibb.co/ZXV6r3Z/logo-large.png">
<meta property="og:description" content="Website Description">
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta name="author" content="Author name">
```

From the browser Inspector I have confirmed that these tags are being loaded in the DOM but still no image thumbnail for my website URL appears in Whatsapp. Please help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `og:image:secure_url` image path attribute did not load the image. The problem was solved after providing a url to a static image in my Django project:

```
{% load static %}
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="{% static 'images/logo-large.png' %}">
```