# Thumbnail and Description are not being Displayed on Whatsapp Preview Link

Tags: html, vue.js, facebook-opengraph, thumbnails, whatsapp

I know there are similar questions about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-an-image-for-whatsapp-link-sharing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100917/showing-thumbnail-for-link-in-whatsapp-ogimage-meta-tag-doesnt-work).

I have done the mandatory steps of 2020 standard from those links but description and thumbnail are still not being displayed on WhatsApp.

The link that I have been testing is: https://research.verdhana.id/TEST

My website is already secured by SSL with valid SSL certificate (not self-signed).
The thumbnail is a JPEG image with size of 18KB and 400x400 dimension.

I use Vue.js and I do not use server side rendering, so I put all the mandatory meta tags inside index.html so they can be read by crawler even javascript is not executed.

The og:image tag already uses full path and same domain.
The og:url meta tag will always be the same for any URL path because it is written in the index.html, but I think it should not be a problem.

Here are the tags inside head tag:

```
<head>
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="my_fb_id" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://research.verdhana.id/logo.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="400" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Verdhana | Research" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Verdhana research website" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://research.verdhana.id" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Verdhana | Research" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>logo.ico" />
  <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>logo.ico" />
  <title>Verdhana | Research</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Verdhana research website" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" />
</head>
```

My website description and thumbnail are still not shown by WhatsApp like you can see below.
[image: WhatsApp not showing description and thumbnail]

I tried to get preview on [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and [iframely](https://iframely.com/embed) and both of them show the description and thumbnail.
[image: Facebook Debugger preview]
[image: Iframely embedded preview]

EDIT:
I have added fb:app_id tag but still not showing.

Are there any missing steps I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried it with my WhatsApp and it's working fine for me:

[image]

Comment: That is interesting, because I also asked some of my friends that never opened the link and they got no thumbnail and description. Did you do something uncommon like maybe clean WhatsApp cache first or else?

Comment: This was on WhatsApp desktop, just tried it on mobile and it doesn't show the image or description. Really odd, don't see any reason for it to do that

Comment: I also tried a couple of my sites on mobile, one of them doesn't show the image or description, one of them does. Both configured exactly the same except for the content.

Comment: Did you find any odd characters in the configuration of the one that did not show image or description?

Comment: Yes! The description has `⭒ Logos ⭒ Instagram design ⭒ Creative direction ⭒...`

Comment: Weird if that's the issue as it works perfectly fine for Facebook mobile

Comment: Do  all of your websites have fb:app_id tag?

Comment: I thought fb:app_id is mandatory but I checked several websites that shown on Whatsapp, they do not have that tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218613/discussion-between-chrisma-daniel-and-daniel-knights).

Comment: Same for me. Works on WhatsApp on Windows, but not on Android. ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, link preview is working on Facebook but not on WhatsApp :(

Comment: we are also facing this problem in the whats app,.. any updates for this? :(

Answer (score 1):

Probably does not apply in case of the OP, but dumping this answer here for others with a similar issue.

In our case, the issue was that the `og:image` URL did not include a file extension (`.jpg`). We are using Cloudinary, and in their case file extensions in the image URLs are not required.

Once we added the `.jpg` to the image URL, the image started showing up in the Whatsapp previews.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the value for `og:url` matches the full URL https://research.verdhana.id/TEST

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://research.verdhana.id/TEST" />
```