# don't working Og in meta tag in sharing link

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, image, facebook-opengraph

I set all Og tags to my website.
But when I share a link from my website on social networks such as WhatsApp and Telegram, the image and other information is not displayed.

[image]

[image]

I even tried with a small photo but it still did not show
What is the problem?
I did a lot of research but I still haven't succeeded.
Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Have you checked: https://css-tricks.com/essential-meta-tags-social-media/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the address in the og:url should be exactly like the address of site.

Then, if this address is complete(https://www.websiteurl...) will be shown in Telegram and WhatsApp. If it does not have one of the "https" and "www" ,information may not be displayed in one.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with Open Graphs tags... Facebook keeps updating the tags and their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/) does not make it clear.

I suggest copy-pasting your url in [Open Graph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) which would highlight any issues with your OG tags.

I don't see any issues with your tags, but you might want to include the following tags:

```
og:image:url
og:site_name
og:country-name
```

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100917/showing-thumbnail-for-link-in-whatsapp-ogimage-meta-tag-doesnt-work) might be helpful.