# og:image works great on all social media except WhatsApp

Tags: html, css, image, header, social-networking

With great, I mean: it looks very nice, but when I try to do it on WhatsApp, the sizes are not correct and the logo is only shown partially.

Is there a practical way to make it shine on all social media, including WhatsApp e.g. by resizing the image specifically for WhatsApp?

If not, what size should I use or what would you recommend me to do this in this case?

Comment: Check out this solution: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100917/showing-thumbnail-for-link-in-whatsapp-ogimage-meta-tag-doesnt-work) Maybe it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not have any issues showing it. It's just the image size...