# Open Graph og:image preview thumbnail shows up fine on iMessage, but not on WhatsApp

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp, meta-tags, imessage

Scowered around for help with this and can't figure out why this isn't working.

I have my Open Graph image set with the following two lines of code (which should be all that is needed):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://myurl.com/logo.png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300">
```

The full preview (not just the smaller icon) shows up just fine on iMessage but no image at all shows up on WhatsApp. People have said that the image should be no bigger than 300px (hence the second tag setting that), and the image file itself is only 9kb.

Would super appreciate any direction or additional things I should be trying as WhatsApp guidelines are not very clear.

Thank you!

Edit with updated tags (still not working):

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SiteName">
<meta property="og:url" content="myurl.com" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta property="og:image" content="myurl.com/logo.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400">
```

Comment: I’ve never seen anything about only needing just two lines of code for Open Graph images. On my sites, I specify the `og:url` and `site_name`, and two `og:image` data sets for a 1200 x 630 and a 400 x 400 image with width, height, alt, and type. The 400x400 image is second and WhatsApp uses that image. I also include twitter meta data include card (I use summary). WhatsApp, in the past, seemed to refer to the twitter card specification.

Comment: @RichDeBourke Thanks for the insight! I have made my image 400x400 px and changed the code to the following but still it seems to make no difference on WhatsApp. Any other potential things I could be missing? (see edits above)

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100917/showing-thumbnail-for-link-in-whatsapp-ogimage-meta-tag-doesnt-work