# OG Image not showing on WhatsApp

Tags: html, css, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp, static-pages

I have a static webpage at [www.poggenamp.com](http://www.poggenamp.com). I have added OG tags to the `<head>` element but for some reason the OG image will not show on WhatsApp. I am quite new to this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I added the `itemprop` tag to the OG Image meta tag, as well as specified the `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` but unfortunately the image does not show on WhatsApp when sharing the link. The title, description as well as the URL do show up but not the image.

```
<!-- OG Tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.poggenamp.com" />
    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="https://www.poggenamp.com/images/PANog.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="526" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="275" />
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Motor Stampings and Transformer Laminations Manufacturer"    />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="West India's Largest Manufacturer of Stampings and Laminations"    />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Poggenamp Group" />
```

Comment: [Is this any help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100917/showing-thumbnail-for-link-in-whatsapp-ogimage-meta-tag-doesnt-work)

Comment: @Adam - adding the "secure_url" to the og-image tag worked!!

Comment: Awesome!!! Glad you got it sorted.