Image not shown on preview while sharing link on whatsapp
I am facing an issue while sharing my link on whatsapp it didn't preview image in thumbnail.
<meta property="og:type" content="Product Detail" />
<meta property="og:title" content="{{product.name|title}} | {{product.store.name|title}}" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Stocks Maze" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{{SERVER_BASE_URL}}{{product.image.0.image}}" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.stocksmaze.com/product-detail/{{product.id}}/">
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{{product.description}} from seller {{product.store.name|title}}.">


Here is the list of tags i'm using on my product details page
What do i need to change so that it start displaying image on whatsapp

This post has related information and or solutions to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100917/showing-thumbnail-for-link-in-whatsapp-ogimage-meta-tag-doesnt-work

I have done all that is mentioned in this answer.but still not working for me

The namespace declaration should be on the html tag rather than the meta tag – <html lang="en" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> and og:type should be one of the recognized types such as website. It also might help to include image width and height. And you may need to clear your cache for WhatsApp per this answer. I don’t know if these things will help with your WhatsApp problem, but something to check.
