# Why shouldn't we place DIV tags in the HEAD tag?

Tags: html

A consultant who is helping us with Microsoft Marketing has recently sent me a snippet of code to add to our website. The code contains both SCRIPT tags and DIV tags and should be placed in the HEAD tag according to him. I questioned that at first because DIV's shouldn't be placed in HEAD but he persisted and I did as told. Now we are setting up a routine where we on a regular basis will set up registration pages, where each time this type of code (with both DIVs and SCRIPTs) will be placed in the HEAD element of those pages. It looks like it works but I prefer to follow HTML standards. How bad a violation is this? Should I just roll with it as long as it works and what are the risks?

Comment: Why do you **want** to put a `<div>`  in the `<head>` ? Why should that make sense?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Placing a DIV in <head>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088555/placing-a-div-in-head)

Comment: A div tag is used to **display** something, but the head tag isn't intended for elements that are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How bad a violation is this?

Your HTML is invalid. Quoting the spec on the [`<div>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element):

> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>
> - Where flow content is expected.
> - As a child of a dl element.

The second one is easy: a `<head>` element is not a `<dl>`. How about the first? What can a [`<head>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-head-element) contain?

> Content model:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise: One or more elements of **metadata content**, of which exactly one is a `title` element and no more than one is a base element.

The `<head>` element cannot contain flow content.

What can a [`<body>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element) contain?

> Content model:
>
> - Flow content.

It's the appropriate parent for a `<div>` element.

> Should I just roll with it as long as it works and what are the risks?

The browser will be doing this:

1. It starts to evaluate your page. So far, your HTML is valid.
2. It sees a `<div>` element. Technically, you don't need to close the `</head>`, so the page is not yet invalid.

   - First, it implicitly renders a `</head>`,
   - starts a `<body>`
   - and then renders your `<div>`
3. It might now encounter more of your the elements that should be in the `<head>` but are not. It will *do its best* to use these metadata tags (like `<link>`, `<meta>`, etc.). Already ambiguity seeps in.
4. It will then encounter the `<body>` you wrote yourself. It will now have to either ignore it or merge it *in some way* with the implicitly opened `<body>`.

It re-shuffles some of your HTML so that the DOM tree is somewhat sensible. You've lost control of what you want the browser to do and are up to its whims.

Comment: Thank you!  This explanation will help me explain why we should not be following the suggested procedure. I noticed when I ran the website through HTML validation that it said that I had a trailing </head> tag. I didn't understand it because the source code only has one </head>. But with your explanation it makes sense if it can't render <div> without first closing the head

Answer (score 2):

You can put divs in `<header>` as of HTML5, but never in `<head>`.
`<head>` is reserved for metadata, loading css...
Elements in the `<body>` part are the ones that will be displayed on the website, the `<head>` elements are like the "backend" of your frontend.
`<div>` goes in the `<body>` part of the website, but never in the `<head>`

The reason is that the user experience will be unpredictable.
If it works, it's because today's browsers are very forgiving, but it's better not to tempt the fate. It'll work until some point when it's gonna create huge problems.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head