# How do you code in a preview description and preview image for your website?

Tags: java, html, css, metadata

I'm trying to figure out how to tell my website what image/description to use when someone posts a link to my website. Do you know how?

Comment: Posts a link where?  If it's on my website, for example, I can put whatever I like.

Comment: for example, Facebook.  A preview image of the website pops up when you share a link, so just trying to figure out how to choose that image.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Facebook has documentation of this, look on their site for instructions.

Comment: This is something that will vary site-to-site, and you will need to make the appropriate changes based on each site's requirements.  Facebook's, for example, can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to update your meta tags... 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43154489/7899146

This will Help!  **:)**

Comment: **Happy Coding**