# How to add a meta og:image tag in woocommerce product details page and set image as product image?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to wordpress.

To show product image while sharing on whatsapp, I want this **og:image** meta tag on the details page of that specific product.

So I tried in the head section of my theme file:

```
if ( is_product() ) {

    global $product;
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$product->get_image($size = 'shop_thumbnail').'">';
}
```

But I get an error :

> Call to a member function get_image() on a non-object

How do I echo the image url in this meta tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code for get the image

```
<?php
 if ( is_product() ) {
    global $post, $product;
    echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'shop_thumbnail' ).'">';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. your code worked like a charm. you are so cute! :)

Comment: Welcome! Happy to Help :)

Comment: though the image url is correctly echoed, but I still can't see the product image while sharing on whatsapp can you help?

Comment: you can follow the step for meta tag :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-a-picture-for-whatsapp-link-sharing

Comment: reading the same question but couldn't get the image there. do you think I need to all the steps from 1 to 10 in the above question to see the image there?

Comment: can you please provide an answer to above question on that question's page? I'm there.

Comment: ok. try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/addonist-whatsapp-share/