# How can I convert link as like attached image?

Tags: android

[image]

What this is called?

How to implement?

Is there any Lib/API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Provide an image for WhatsApp link sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-an-image-for-whatsapp-link-sharing)

Comment: it's preview of the link

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called **Rich Link**.

Rich Links Can Be easily implemented using  [Android Link Preview Library](https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview)

It is attained by adding the following to the gradle

add following repository

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
  maven { url 'https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy' }
}
```

Add the following gradle file

```
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3' // required
compile 'com.leocardz:link-preview:2.0.0@aar'
```

If you are using Proguard Rules add the following rule

```
-keeppackagenames org.jsoup.nodes
```

Implementation

**Intialisation**

```
import com.leocardz.link.preview.library.TextCrawler;
// ...
// Create an instance of the TextCrawler to parse your url into a preview.
TextCrawler textCrawler = new TextCrawler();

// ..

// Create the callbacks to handle pre and post exicution of the preview generation.
LinkPreviewCallback linkPreviewCallback = new LinkPreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPre() {
        // Any work that needs to be done before generating the preview. Usually inflate 
        // your custom preview layout here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onPos(SourceContent sourceContent, boolean b) {
        // Populate your preview layout with the results of sourceContent.
    }
};
```

**Generate Preview**

```
textCrawler.makePreview( linkPreviewCallback, url);
```

Try this please

[Here is Another Library.](https://github.com/FreesoulApps/PreviewAndroid)

Comment: can you show us how to implement in recycler view