# Open graph: List of global types

Tags: facebook-opengraph

## My use case

I am building a website for a conference, with `opengraph` attributes for Facebook and Twitter sharing.

The [validator](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Ftlv.serverlessdays.io%2F) says that the `og:type` field is mandatory:

[image]

So, I added a field:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="..." />
```

## My problem

I am not sure what is my content type. [The manual states that](http://ogp.me/#types):

> In order for your object to be represented within the graph, you need to specify its type. This is done using the og:type property:
>
> ```
> <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
> ```
>
> When the community agrees on the schema for a type, it is added to the list of global types.

However, I could not find a list of "global types", and I am not sure what is the type of my conference webpage.

## My question

**Where can I find a list of global object types for open graph objects?**

Comment: Did you find an answer to this elsewhere? I have the exact same question.

Comment: @Adam did you manage to find a list of types?  I been searching everywhere.

Comment: Only one I can find is:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/

Comment: @torbenrudgaard this developers page by Facebook is really good. Especially if you’re only looking to provide an Open Graph Protocol for sharing links with Facebook.

Comment: @AdamMatan Did you find your answer elsewhere or did I answer your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51701628/6086226) correctly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here’s the website of Open Graph Protocol: http://ogp.me/. Where ***ogp*** stands for Open Graph Protocol.

---

### Explanation

On this website you can see all the OGP objects and it’s possible object types provided with an explanation of their purpose.

---

### The list

On this website they are also talking about a global list of object types. And when a global object type is accepted by the community it is added to [**The Global List**](http://ogp.me/#types). What this suggests is that there is in fact a (apparently virtual) list of global object types! But the fact is you can create one yourself as well!

Here’s Facebook’s global list of object types: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/.

Also Schema (https://schema.org/) has a list of *commonly used* types. I would really recommend using Schema, since it’s used by Google to see how well you have documented your website (hence the name *"[Structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)"*). Google also pulls out given tables, search bar, the website’s page structure, ratings/reviews, products and prizes and much more.

---

### Example

Let's take a look at a random movie on **the old** [imdb.com](https://imdb.com): "[The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160315141252/http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120737/)". We see the tag used here:

`<meta property='og:type' content="video.movie" />`

Now if you would search the title online (let's use Google), we see the cast, duration, covers, genre, release year, box office. It's all collected by Google.

Nowadays, imdb uses `image` as their `og:type`. I'm sure why... maybe they want Google to fetch their data differently, or Google doesn't use the `video.movie` type anymore (I'll have to do some digging).

**Another example.** Let's search a random product on [Etsy.com](https://www.etsy.com) and throw it in the [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/). We see that Google knows this is a product! Because they have the meta tag:

`<meta property="og:type" content="product" />`

Now this product will most likely be visible in [Google Shopping](https://www.google.com/search?q=product&tbm=shop) as well!

---

### Conclusion

I think you need to ask yourself why you would need this meta tag and it’s properties. I always put it in, but it always says ***website***.

It’s cool you can create this list of global object types yourself, or use the types provided by your *target* (Facebook in your example). But is it really worth all this trouble? I created many websites without it and they preview their links beautifully on WhatsApp, Twitter and Facebook! Goodluck.

---

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43154489/6086226) for even more information about meta tags!

Comment: But the https://ogp.me/#types page does not seem to be actively maintained ([Last update](https://github.com/facebook/open-graph-protocol/commits/master/index.php) in 2016). For example it doesn't mention `product.item` which is used on many online shops.

Comment: @dolmen I think it's good to *View Page Source* on different websites to find things like `product.item`. Like you did!

Comment: This is really confusing for an official spec. That LOR link is a webpage about a movie, not a video.movie. Are you that is the correct usage type? That denotes webpage subject matter. But then why is there a `webpage` type?

Comment: @BenRacicot apparently, these days, imdb links use `<meta property="og:type" content="image"/>` instead of the `video.movie` type. And the `webpage` type has been changed to `website`, I'll change this.

Comment: Something unclear to me is if you also have to explicitly add the namespace declaration to the `<head>` or that these standard types are recognized by default.

Comment: @dolmen there's `og:product` type available, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/product/

Answer (score 16):

> **og:Type Lists Of Objects**
>
> **apps.saves** An action representing someone saving an app to try later.
>
> **article** This object represents an article on a website. It is the preferred type for blog posts and news stories.
>
> **book** This object type represents a book or publication. This is an appropriate type for ebooks, as well as traditional paperback or
>   hardback books. Do not use this type to represent magazines
>
> **books.author** This object type represents a single author of a book.
>
> **books.book** This object type represents a book or publication. This is an appropriate type for ebooks, as well as traditional paperback or
>   hardback books
>
> **books.genre** This object type represents the genre of a book or publication.
>
> **books.quotes** Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
>
> An action representing someone quoting from a book.
>
> **books.rates** Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
>
> An action representing someone rating a book.
>
> **books.reads** Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
>
> An action representing someone reading a book.
>
> **books.wants_to_read** Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
>
> An action representing someone wanting to read a book.
>
> **business.business** This object type represents a place of business that has a location, operating hours and contact information.
>
> **fitness.bikes** Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
>
> An action representing someone cycling a course.
>
> **fitness.course** This object type represents the user's activity contributing to a particular run, walk, or bike course.
>
> **fitness.runs** Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
>
> An action representing someone running a course.
>
> **fitness.walks** Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
>
> An action representing someone walking a course.
>
> **game.achievement** This object type represents a specific achievement in a game. An app must be in the 'Games' category in App
>   Dashboard to be able to use this object type. Every achievement has a 
>   game:points value associate with it. This is not related to the points
>   the user has scored in the game, but is a way for the app to indicate
>   the relative importance and scarcity of different achievements: * Each
>   game gets a total of 1,000 points to distribute across its
>   achievements * Each game gets a maximum of 1,000 achievements *
>   Achievements which are scarcer and have higher point values will
>   receive more distribution in Facebook's social channels. For example,
>   achievements which have point values of less than 10 will get almost
>   no distribution. Apps should aim for between 50-100 achievements
>   consisting of a mix of 50 (difficult), 25 (medium), and 10 (easy)
>   point value achievements Read more on how to use achievements in this
>   guide.
>
> **games.achieves** An action representing someone reaching a game achievement.
>
> **games.celebrate** An action representing someone celebrating a victory in a game.
>
> **games.plays** An action representing someone playing a game. Stories for this action will only appear in the activity log.
>
> **games.saves** An action representing someone saving a game.
>
> **music.album** This object type represents a music album; in other words, an ordered collection of songs from an artist or a collection
>   of artists. An album can comprise multiple discs.
>
> **music.listens** Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
>
> An action representing someone listening to a song, album, radio
>   station, playlist or musician
>
> **music.playlist** This object type represents a music playlist, an ordered collection of songs from a collection of artists.
>
> **music.playlists** Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
>
> An action representing someone creating a playlist.
>
> **music.radio_station** This object type represents a 'radio' station of a stream of audio. The audio properties should be used to identify
>   the location of the stream itself.
>
> **music.song** This object type represents a single song.
>
> **news.publishes** An action representing someone publishing a news article.
>
> **news.reads** Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
>
> An action representing someone reading a news article.
>
> **og.follows** An action representing someone following a Facebook user
>
> **og.likes** An action representing someone liking any object.
>
> **pages.saves** An action representing someone saving a place.
>
> **place** This object type represents a place - such as a venue, a business, a landmark, or any other location which can be identified by
>   longitude and latitude.
>
> **product** This object type represents a product. This includes both virtual and physical products, but it typically represents items that
>   are available in an online store.
>
> **product.group** This object type represents a group of product items.
>
> **product.item** This object type represents a product item.
>
> **profile** This object type represents a person. While appropriate for celebrities, artists, or musicians, this object type can be used
>   for the profile of any individual. The **fb:profile_id** field
>   associates the object with a Facebook user.
>
> **restaurant.menu** This object type represents a restaurant's menu. A restaurant can have multiple menus, and each menu has multiple
>   sections.
>
> **restaurant.menu_item** This object type represents a single item on a restaurant's menu. Every item belongs within a menu section.
>
> **restaurant.menu_section** This object type represents a section in a restaurant's menu. A section contains multiple menu items.
>
> **restaurant.restaurant** This object type represents a restaurant at a specific location.
>
> **restaurant.visited** An action representing someone visiting a restaurant.
>
> **restaurant.wants_to_visit** An action representing someone wanting to visit a restaurant
>
> **sellers.rates** An action representing a commerce seller has been given a rating.
>
> **video.episode** This object type represents an episode of a TV show and contains references to the actors and other professionals involved
>   in its production. An episode is defined by us as a full-length
>   episode that is part of a series. This type must reference the series
>   this it is part of.
>
> **video.movie** This object type represents a movie, and contains references to the actors and other professionals involved in its
>   production. A movie is defined by us as a full-length feature or short
>   film. Do not use this type to represent movie trailers, movie clips,
>   user-generated video content, etc.
>
> **video.other** This object type represents a generic video, and contains references to the actors and other professionals involved in
>   its production. For specific types of video content, use the
>   **video.movie** or **video.tv**_show object types. This type is for any other type of video content not represented elsewhere (eg.
>   trailers, music videos, clips, news segments etc.)
>
> **video.rates** Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
>
> An action representing someone rating a movie, TV show, episode or
>   another piece of video content.
>
> **video.tv**_show This object type represents a TV show, and contains references to the actors and other professionals involved in its
>   production. For individual episodes of a series, use the video.episode
>   object type. A TV show is defined by us as a series or set of episodes
>   that are produced under the same title (eg. a television or online
>   series)
>
> **video.wants_to_watch** Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
>
> An action representing someone wanting to watch video content.
>
> **video.watches** Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
>
> An action representing someone watching video content.

Comment: What's the source?

Comment: @AdamMatan ogp.me

Comment: I don't think ogp.me shows type product anymore. The only source I could find now is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/product/

Comment: where do you find the official list?