# Website Title Whatsapp

Tags: php, html, tags, web, meta

i have a little Question if I post some URL in Whatsapp Conversation, the Logo and the Website title are automaticlay load and the Partner can see the logo from the URL etc.

How i can implement this to my site shoud i work with Facebook and Twitter Integration tags like :

```html
        <!-- Facebook and Twitter integration -->
        <meta property="og:title" content=""/>
        <meta property="og:image" content=""/>
        <meta property="og:url" content=""/>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
        <meta property="og:description" content=""/>
        <meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
        <meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
        <meta name="twitter:url" content="" />
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="" />
```

Or should i work with Meta Tags if yes which tags for URL Description and which Tag for Logo ?

Comment: Fyi, those are meta tags too. Just integrate them in your site and see if it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Provide an image for WhatsApp link sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-an-image-for-whatsapp-link-sharing)

Comment: Check out http://ogp.me/ for the opengraph (`og:`) meta tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use open graph tags, read http://ogp.me/. basically all you need is

```
<meta property="og:image" content="url_image">
```

and make sure the image is less than 300kb. but you can find complete info to use [Provide an image for WhatsApp link sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-an-image-for-whatsapp-link-sharing).