# mvc view Show preview when sharing (Facebook,whatsapp,Twitter)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i know that might be stupid Question and even get negative votes
 but i really need to know the answer

in some websites when share the url it shows a preview for the website
check the image [image: Facebook Cooment]

[image: WhatsApp]

now i have a MVC View works fine on browser and also om mobile (responsive)
but when sharing it only share the url text

do i need to add some thing to my view to do the same preview when sharing over social media 
my URL : http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/SiteName/newspreview/ShowOneNews/4333
the x is static IP For the server Not yet have Domain Name
Thank you

Comment: Since i had no answer i found the answer my self [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-an-image-for-whatsapp-link-sharing)

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp would render a preview for your website but you can improve that. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43154489/592651