# Add a preview to html link tag

Tags: css, html, web-deployment

**When we share some links it displays a link preview an image and some texts.** How do we add to our http links? Hope my question is clear.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43154489/6613333

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OG might be the thing you are looking for.
It is a group of meta tags with specific properties, they handle title, description and image displayed after link is shared.
More here: [about OG](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/)