# Adding image to html title not favicon

Tags: html

I want to add an image to my page so when I share the link it shows the image and description just as it is in the pics below or something similar
so It doesn't just show the link description alone but also shows image.

[image: Image in html title so it would show on link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a favicon showing with the link. og used to show the image and description.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="//cdn.example.com/uploads/images/webpage_300x200.png">
```

Check this stackoverflow topic [Provide an image for WhatsApp link sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-an-image-for-whatsapp-link-sharing)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info).