# Why WhatsApp web does not show og image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-opengraph

I have a [website](https://dev.greenbrands.ru/) that dynamically applies meta tags and I use ReactJS with SSR. Og image works in skype, facebook, twitter, but only in WhatsApp it does not work.

I tried using the following tags but it didn't work

```
  <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="" />
  <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="" />
  <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="400" />
```

Can you tell me what the problem might be ?

Comment: Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-an-image-for-whatsapp-link-sharing/43154489#:~:text=og%3Aurl%20%3A%20Full%20link%20to,dimensions%2032%20x%2032%20pixels.) solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the source of your image , in other words you need to define the path for the image.

For eg :

```
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content= {`${DOMAIN}/static/images/metalogo.jpg`} />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content={`${DOMAIN}/static/images/metalogo.jpg`} />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400" />
```