# Best way to share interactable content via messaging apps?

Tags: flutter

trying to create the ability for users to share a digital business card like creation via email, messaging, etc. I know there are packages for sharing content but they all seem pretty basic. What's the best way to send interactive cards view messenger and other similar apps?

I know there are plugins such as https://pub.dev/packages/share but it does not seem to support anything more advanced than text and images? Feel free to correct that if this is not the case.

Here is an example of what I'm to implement for sharing:

[image]

What's the best way to send interactive snippets like this through email and messaging?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For email, you probably want to send an HTML page.
For whatsapp etc. maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-an-image-for-whatsapp-link-sharing) is related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can design the required UI card in flutter and convert that component in the form of an image and then using [share](https://pub.dev/packages/share) package you can share it with other social media apps.
Use [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) package or any other similar package to convert widget to the image.