# How to Get Title and Brief Description from a URL in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, url

In Discord, if you post a link, Discord will find the title, and a brief summary of the linked webpage: [image]

How can I replicate this behavior in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43154489/9964778

You need to get the value of some meta tags which starts with "og". In [your example](https://www.livescience.com/alien-glowing-cheeto-sea-cucumber), you have in the source code below with the related metadata for title, description, image, among other fields

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="livescience.com">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/W3wpBCQ4hEL4dthLYnsosK-1200-80.gif">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/livescience?cmpid=556687">
<meta property="og:title" content="Alien shopping-bag ocean weirdo has glowing Cheetos for guts">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.livescience.com/alien-glowing-cheeto-sea-cucumber">
<meta property="og:description" content="The deep-sea creature surprised scientists.">
```