# In Quarto how do I write inline CSS

Tags: css, r, quarto

I would like to color a word in a sentence that is being rendered in quarto to HTML.  In R Markdown I would just add a css tag but I don't see how to do that in quarto.  The [quarto documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/visual-editor/content.html#defining-styles) says that it is possible to write inline css but there is no example.  There is a hyperlink that shows a R Markdown example:

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
body {
  color: red;
}
```
````

When I do that, quarto displays the code as a code block and does not use the CSS.

How do I add a CSS code block to a quarto document?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just surround the word you want to style by `[]` and write the styles in `{}`, like this

```
the color is [red]{style="color: red;"}
```

so the word `red` will be in the color red.

To add more details,

```
---
title: "inline style"
format: html
---

## inline style in Quarto

We can apply styles to a sentence or a word 
by creating spans using `[]` to surround the
sentence or word that we want to style and 
use `{}` to define the style that we want to 
apply. For example,

The color of this word is [red]{style="color: red;"}. 
And [this line has a yellow background]{style="background-color: yellow"}.
```

After rendering, we get this,

[image: quarto-doc-with-inline-css]

Comment: Thank you so much @shafee. This is perfect.  You should fork the quarto documentation on GitHub and add this example.

Comment: @itsMeInMiami, it is already there, I think [this is it](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/markdown-basics.html#divs-and-spans).

Comment: @shafee How do we add meta tags so that when we share the HTML file in chat ( whatsapp or others) display like this [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-an-image-for-whatsapp-link-sharing). I specifically, want to share a self-contain html report as text, but would like to display some info in the image and text, rather than just a file name

Comment: @user5249203, can please make a separate question so that others along with me can answer that properly : ) ?

Comment: here is the [new SO post with Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73925668/sharing-self-contained-html-file-as-text)