# embed my website in whatsapp chat like youtube link share

Tags: html, iframe, picture-in-picture

I want to show my website content in picture in picture tab in whatsapp as like youtube.

when we share a youtube link in whatsapp chat, it will send as a preview and when anyone click on that , it will open a small window (picture in picture) inside whatsapp & show an iframe of youtube website & play it as same as in youtube.

I want this type of functionality for my website.
what can i do for this, i used open graph in meta tags but it only shows image preview on link sharing, it will not open a small popup for my website as it does for youtube.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Provide an image for WhatsApp link sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-an-image-for-whatsapp-link-sharing)

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-an-image-for-whatsapp-link-sharing