# Controlling Copy/Paste and Sharing Into Social Media

Tags: django, hyperlink, clipboard

I'm not sure what this is called, but I figured one of you might know. Once I know what I'm looking for I can do some googling.

So I have a django web app that I've been working on. I have a list of model instances that the user will be able to view on the front end. The model includes a bunch of data and an one or more images. I'd like to be able to share a link to that model from within the list.

Now, when I share a link on Facebook or whatever, the link generally transforms into an image of the content rather than just the link. Like a youtube video would show up as a link and a screen cap of the video that you can click on and navigate to that page.

How do you do that? Like, control what ends up in that image? I ask because when I paste a link from my site, all I get is a link (and for some reason Facebook blocks me from even sending the link in messenger)

Additionally I'd like for someone to be able to click a button to copy/paste a summary of the data and the image to share via SMS, messenger and or social media. Like how do I control the content of that copy/paste so that a user doesn't have to select the whole html view or what have you?

thanks for your time and knowledge,

EK

Comment: I think you are looking for open graph preview tags? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778620/provide-an-image-for-whatsapp-link-sharing/43154489#43154489

Comment: I've never heard of that but I will do some googling on the subject, thank you.!