# I can't change my Favicon size

Tags: html, favicon

I can't change my favicon size even after I give it sizes="32x32" it doesn't change and I don't know where is the problem.

My code:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="Images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32"/>
```

Comment: try to open the favicon directly in the browser. (STRG + F5 and see if the new favicon (in the correct size) is displayed in the browser

Comment: Where exactly are you displaying the favicon?

Comment: I tried to open it in the browser and yes it is in the correct size.

I display it in the tab.

Comment: But most (all?) desktop browser tab icons are fixed size...

Comment: That's why I am getting mad in here. I don't know what is the problem and where it is.

Comment: Then problem is that when you run a computer program it won't change its appearance if its author has not coded such feature. Browsers are not an exception.

Answer (score 4):

The size attribute is not supported in any of the major browsers. [HTML link sizes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_sizes.asp). [This site](http://www.xiconeditor.com/) will let you create 32x32 icons. [Here's a stackoverflow question that may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268204/favicon-dimensions). Another helpful answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19590415/4760460), in this answer there is a better favicon generator. [Here's](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) the link to it.

Comment: You can change the size of your icon [here](http://www.xiconeditor.com/).

Comment: I've edited my answer that links you to a site that can change the size of your favicon and a link to a stackoverflow question that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this is the best option:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon. png" sizes="16x16 32x32" type="image/png">
```