# What dimensions should a large, single, PNG favicon be?

Tags: android, ios, png, favicon

To make my life easier I intend to create one large PNG favicon. I will use this as my favicon and Apple Touch Icon. I understand that browsers and devices will scale this one file to the necassary dimensions. See [Can one large size favicon serve all devices and browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939439/can-one-large-size-favicon-serve-all-devices-and-browsers/45074134#45074134)

1. But what dimensions should this one PNG be? I guess I couldn't go far wrong with making it 200x200px? I don't think favicons or Apple Touch Icons are bigger than this?
2. Do Window PCs and phones and Android phones use the favicon icon? Or like iOS (Apple Touch Icons) do I have to write a link to the PNG?

Thank you

Comment: try https://realfavicongenerator.net/

Comment: From the link in my opening post, I understand that it is now possible to create just one large PNG file. I'm just wondering what size this should be. I want to be able to create favicons in my design software without having to use a favicon generator.

Comment: I've had time to check out your suggestion. It works very well. Thank you